# Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is not a field

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a a class of subset of $\Omega$ s.t.

- $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$
- $A\in \mathcal{A}$ implies $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$
- $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite *disjoint* union.

Show that $\mathcal{A}$ does not have to be a field.

Hint: Try $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the field generated by two point subsets of $Omega$.

The about is a homework question I got. I guess the trick is to use the finite *disjoint* union. Can some help me start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess, that you are not really supposed to try to show, that the *field* generated by two point subsets of $\Omega$ is not a *field*. Rather I guess, you should try to make out of the given $\Omega$ a class of subsets that satisfies the exigencies of the definition.

Such a set would be all two-point subsets of $\Omega$. The complements are also two-pointed and *disjoint* unions are only those in which one set contains the two points missing in the other, thus if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint two-pointed sets $A \cup B = \Omega$.

Thus there are no three-pointed and one-pointed sets in your structure which conflicts with the requirement of intersections being also in $\mathcal{A}$ if it were to be a field.

Thus $\mathcal{A} := \{\Omega, \emptyset, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 4\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{3, 4\}\}$, satisfies all requirements, since it is closed under finite disjoint union and taking complements. Disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$ are only those, that share no element, like $\{1, 4\} \cup \{2, 3\} = \Omega$. Try to get the set $\{1\} = \{1, 4\} \cap \{1, 3\}$ which should be in $\mathcal{A}$ if it were to be a field, out of the present ones by using the axioms of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand. Could you give and example of two-point subsets?

Comment: I've edited my post.